# Grails exception while run-war: NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, grails, deployment, groovy, intellij-idea

I am getting the following exception while running `run-war` on IntelliJ IDEA.

```
| Uglifying File 44 of 464 - application.                     
| Error Error executing script RunWar: com.google.common.collect.Maps.immutableEnumMap(Ljava/util/Map;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap; (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered.
Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Maps.immutableEnumMap(Ljava/util/Map;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap;
        at com.google.javascript.jscomp.parsing.parser.Keywords.<clinit>(Keywords.java:94)
        at com.google.javascript.jscomp.parsing.parser.Scanner.scanIdentifierOrKeyword(Scanner.java:681)
        at com.google.javascript.jscomp.parsing.parser.Scanner.scanToken(Scanner.java:569)
        at com.google.javascript.jscomp.parsing.parser.Scanner.peekToken(Scanner.java:228)
        at com.google.javascript.jscomp.parsing.parser.Parser.peekToken(Parser.java:2737)
        at com.google.javascript.jscomp.parsing.parser.Parser.peekToken(Parser.java:2730)
        at com.google.javascript.jscomp.parsing.parser.Parser.getTreeStartLocation(Parser.java:2649)
        at com.google.javascript.jscomp.parsing.parser.Parser.parseProgram(Parser.java:147)
        at com.google.javascript.jscomp.parsing.ParserRunner.parse(ParserRunner.java:102)
        at com.google.javascript.jscomp.JsAst.parse(JsAst.java:84)
        at com.google.javascript.jscomp.JsAst.getAstRoot(JsAst.java:50)
        at com.google.javascript.jscomp.CompilerInput.getAstRoot(CompilerInput.java:118)
        at com.google.javascript.jscomp.Compiler.hoistExterns(Compiler.java:1467)
        at com.google.javascript.jscomp.Compiler.parseInputs(Compiler.java:1369)
        at com.google.javascript.jscomp.Compiler.parse(Compiler.java:788)
        at com.google.javascript.jscomp.Compiler.compileInternal(Compiler.java:743)
        at com.google.javascript.jscomp.Compiler.access$000(Compiler.java:93)
        at com.google.javascript.jscomp.Compiler$3.call(Compiler.java:655)
        at com.google.javascript.jscomp.Compiler$3.call(Compiler.java:652)
        at com.google.javascript.jscomp.Compiler$4.call(Compiler.java:699)
```

If I run the same app using `run-app` it works.

This is BuildConfig.groovy:

```
        build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

        compile ':cache:1.1.8'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:2.1.1"
        compile ":easygrid:1.6.9"
        compile ":twitter-bootstrap:3.3.2.1"
        compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC4'
        compile ":jquery-validation-ui:1.4.9"

        compile ":birt-report:4.3.0.3"

        runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
```

Any idea what it might be? or how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Adding a build-scoped dependency on Guava fixed this issue for me in a Grails 2.5.2 app

```
dependencies {
    // other dependencies go here 
    build 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UseGuavaInYourBuild

Make sure you have two things set in your BuildConfig:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '12.0'
}
```

Just make sure you're using the correct version that you need. Then do a Grails Refresh Dependencies.

Comment: Are you getting the same error? You can also try placing the actual jar into your lib folder. Just make sure it's selected in you Build Path.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Grails 2.5.0 and I fixed it by bumping the guava version to the latest available.

In my `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy`, I now have:

```
dependencies {
  compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '18.0'
}
```

And that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and fix it using the latest asset plugin:
 (compile "org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline:2.11.0")